# glDrawElementsInstanced with varying scissors

Tags: opengl

Is it possible to have different scissor test paramenters for each instance drawn using `glDrawElementsInstanced`? If so, how? If not, what would be the cheapest way to implement the scissor test in the fragment shader and are there any performance considerations in doing so?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't change the scissor rectangle during a draw call. A couple of options come to mind:

- Specify the clip rectangle as a per instance vertex attribute, pass it through to the fragment shader, check for fragments to be within the rectangle, and `discard` them otherwise.
- Apply user clip planes.

The second option should be more efficient, since it allows you to clip away the geometry outside the clip rectangle before it enters the fragment shader.

To apply user clip planes with modern OpenGL, you assign values to elements of the predefined `gl_ClipDistance` array in the vertex shader, and enable `GL_CLIP_DISTANCEi`. Here are the main steps to apply this in your use case:

1. Introduce a per-instance vertex attribute that defines the clip rectangle. You can nicely fit the rectangle description into an attribute of type `vec4`. For example, define the attribute to contain the values (xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax) for the rectangle you want to clip against.
2. In the vertex shader, define the attribute:

   ```
   in vec4 ClipRect;
   ```

   and set the clip distances based on your vertex coordinates `coord`:

   ```
   gl_ClipDistance[0] = coord.x - ClipRect[0];
   gl_ClipDistance[1] = ClipRect[1] - coord.x;
   gl_ClipDistance[2] = coord.y - ClipRect[2];
   gl_ClipDistance[3] = ClipRect[3] - coord.y;
   ```

   Note that the assigned distance must be positive for points you want to keep, negative for points you want to clip. You will also have to make sure that the coordinates you use here are in the same coordinate system that the rectangle boundaries are specified in.
3. In the client code, before starting to draw, enable the clip planes:

   ```
   glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE0);
   glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE1);
   glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE2);
   glEnable(GL_CLIP_DISTANCE3);
   ```